# How to add an int value to a sql column from netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm trying to get my JSpinners value to add to the column in my database,
why is my variable query2 working when I put it in db.update() but not query? What do I need to change?

```
try {
    int points = (int) antalPoäng.getValue();

    String query = "UPDATE ELEVHEM SET HUSPOANG = HUSPOANG" + points + "WHERE ELEVHEMSNAMN ='Gryffindor'";
    String query2 = "UPDATE ELEVHEM SET HUSPOANG = HUSPOANG +1 WHERE ELEVHEMSNAMN ='Gryffindor'";

    if (namnElevhem.getSelectedItem().equals("Gryffindor")) {
        db.update(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The points has been added")
    }
}        
catch(InfException e) {

}
```

Comment: Off topic: matter off opinion and or taste i would make SQL keywords/functions uppercase only and identifiers like database, table and column names all lowercase makes it a bit more easy to read and maintain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in your first query you want to increment the `HUSPOANG` column by some amount.  We could try to just correct your concatenated query string, but it would be much better to use a prepared statement here:

```
String sql = "UPDATE ELEVHEM SET HUSPOANG = HUSPOANG + ? WHERE ELEVHEMSNAMN = 'Gryffindor'";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, points);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

If you want to continue with your current approach, then you would need to fix your query string:

```
String query = "UPDATE ELEVHEM SET HUSPOANG = HUSPOANG + " + points +
    " WHERE ELEVHEMSNAMN = 'Gryffindor'";
```

You were missing some needed spaces, but again it would be preferable to use a prepared statement, which it makes it easy to avoid such formatting problems.